# Run a program as a service on Debian/Linux

Tags: linux, service, debian, reboot

I have an older jetty server I want to turn into as a service on a Debian OS. It should start automatic each time I restart the computer.

Manually I start the server with the two following commands:

1. root@myserver:/# cd /opt/jdk/jetty
2. root@myserver:/opt/jdk/jetty# java jetty

Anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: Did you install it via. apt-get install ? Then it should be working as a service already. service jetty start | stop | restart

Comment: No I just copied the files to the server. Its an old version of Jetty which has no script included. I have tried to modify the 'jetty.sh' script included in the new release of jetty and modify it and place in the init.d folder but it get a little to complicated, so I thought there might be an easier way to do it ? BR Henrik

Answer (score -1):

If you want to start any program on booting you can add that entry in `rc.local`.

```
java /opt/jdk/jetty/jetty
```

It will start on reboot

Comment: Hello Shivam,

Thanks for your suggestion but 
java /opt/jdk/jetty/jetty
throws an error: "Exception  in thread 'main java.lang.noClassDedFoundError: /opt/jdk/jetty/jetty".
I guess I have to indicate the dir too somehow ?

Best regards

Henrik